# Can HBase table scan with timeranges avoid full table scans?

Tags: hbase

Scan operations on HBase tables can be done along with time-ranges. (ref: http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeRange(long, long))

Will such partial scans results in better performance when compared with scans without timeranges?

Can the HBase scans done with timeranges avoid full table scan?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to down vote a question without even mentioning a reason. It's really harsh!

Comment: partial scans of what?. Rowkey or Column Family?

Answer (score 2):

HBase performance.

```
Fastest: Rowkey based Scans
Fast: Column Family based Scans
Normal: Time Stamp based Scans
Slowest: Value Scans
```

Generally Speaking